# PyQt5 - Second Window Threading

Tags: multithreading, pyqt5

Moin,
I'm new to all this, so please be paitient.
My search was not successful ...

I have in PyQT5 main Window a thread updating the GUI.
With app.processEvents() in the thread loop everything works fine.

Now I open from this window a new window as a Form and try to do the same but there is no reference to the main app eventloop. So is the thread itself working in the thread loop and updating the GUI but is not responding to connected signals or slots.

How can I fix this ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Widgets are not thread-safe. If you want to use threads, the only option is to use QThread for the *worker* thread (the part that has a "time consuming" process but has *nothing* related with the UI) and custom signals that are connected to the main thread to update/create widgets.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and I know - I use QThread for it.

Comment: Then please provide a [mre].

Comment: Hello, Just found out ! Sorry Beginner! Needed to pass the app variable itself through the new window and the new thread .... works just fine now.